# objective C in Xcode - NSLog and access other class property

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am a total newbie in Objective-C and Xcode (new to programming as well). I am trying to build a simple card game so I created a `Cards` class with properties and instance methods and imported its header file into "Viewcontroller.m".

However, I do not understand two things:

1. Why the `NSLog` in the "Cards.m" is not displaying in the console as I compile. But `NSLog` in "Viewcontroller.m" displays.
2. Seems I can not call the `Cards` class (`NSMutableArray`) property. Even I initialized it without error in "Cards.m", in "Viewcontroller.m", the array is still empty.

Very appreciate your helps because I am very struggling!

Cards.h:

```
@interface Cards : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* contents;

-(void)makeContents;

@end
```

Cards.m:

```
#import "Cards.h"
@interface Cards()

@end

@implementation Cards

@synthesize contents;

-(id)init{
    if(self==[super init]){
        contents = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:53];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void) makeContents{
     NSArray* suits = @[@"♥︎",@"♠︎",@"♣︎",@"♦︎" ];

     NSArray* ranks = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"J",@"Q",@"K", nil];
     for(NSString* suiting in suits){
        for(NSString* ranking in ranks){
            NSString* cards = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", ranking,suiting];
            [contents addObject:cards];

            NSLog(@"%@", contents);//not displaying in console
        }
    }
}

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Cards.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *flipCount;
@property (nonatomic) int numberOfFlip;

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    Cards* cards = [[Cards alloc]init];

    NSLog(@"%@", cards.contents); //displaying in console, the contents is an empty array still? why??
}

- (IBAction)flipCard:(UIButton *)sender {
}

@end
```

Comment: You have a serious typo in your `init` method for `Cards`. Change `if(self==[super init]){` to `if (self = [super init]) {`. Note the use of `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: in case compiler warn you, do `if ((self = [super init])) {`

Comment: One more tidbit. The output from `NSLog` does not appear while compiling. It appears when the app is actually running.

Comment: oh thanks rmaddy, I was so dumb for that typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues.

1. You should use `=`, not `==` to assign `self` to `[super init]`.
2. The `Cards init` method should call `makeContents` to set itself up.

Update your `init` method like this:

```
-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        contents = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:53];
        [self makeContents];
    }

    return self;
}
```

This also means that `makeContents` should only be called by the `Cards` class itself. So you should remove the declaration of `- (void)makeContents` from the .h file.

Also, using `@synthesize` as you have it is unnecessary. Simply remove that line. And try to find a more up-to-date tutorial that doesn't use such outdated code.

Comment: thanks rmaddy, i shouldn't have forgotten to call the method, great advice!

Answer (score 0):

You create and define the method `makeContents` but never actually call it anywhere.  Try calling it in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Cards* cards = [[Cards alloc]init];
    [cards makeContents];
     NSLog(@"%@", cards.contents); //displaying in console, the contents is an empty array still? why??

}
```

Comment: Don't forget the call to `[super viewDidLoad];`.

Comment: @rmaddy Naturally I agree, I'm just trying to illustrate that the reason the OPs code isn't working is simply because he isn't calling it.  Feel free to edit my post.

Comment: @user2864813 You are welcome, please carefully read over the answer by rmaddy also, as his addresses some other problems that you should be aware of.  You can mark only one answer correct, but can upvote both.

Comment: unfortunately I can not upvote any answers for now because I do not have enough credit

Comment: actually one more question, NSLog seems not displaying outside of "ViewController.m", like the one I defined in "Cards.m", I had a very difficult time to debug the codes in "Cards.m" earlier. Any advices?

Comment: You shouldn't really call `NSLog` in a header file.

Comment: sorry typo again, I meant "Cards.m" , i just edited my question, I am trying to find a way that I can debug my codes anytime